# Docker-compose MySQL link failure

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

**EDIT: I've managed to get it to work**

I'm currently using docker in combination with a Dockerfile and a docker-compose.yml i'm trying to run my backend so i can use Postman to get data from the database. However I keep getting Communication Link Failure
`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /build/libs/assignment_4-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar spring-docker.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "spring-docker.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  docker-mysql:
    restart: always
    container_name: docker-mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  app:
    image: springio/docker
    expose:
      - "8080"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: mysql:3306
    depends_on:
      - docker-mysql
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306/database
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

# To keep the database connection alive while idle for a long time 
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

The API is made with SpringBoot using Kotlin. Can someone help me figure out how to resolve this problem?

Comment: This is caused by mysql service not being ready yet, your java service need to wait until mysql service is ready to accept connections, check this https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ and https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it you can test this by restarting your app service container.

Comment: I have added the line `command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "docker-mysql:3306"]` however the problem persists. I've tried to restart the app service container before but that didn't work back then and it doesn't now. Any other ideas?

Comment: what did you put in `wait-for-it.sh` file? can you update your question to include it as well.

Comment: I had just added that to my docker-compose file. I didnt create a wait-for-it.sh file myself since in the documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ 
It seemed like there was already a predefined file for that

Comment: Just download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh, and put the file in same the same directory of docker-compose.yml and then you are good to go.

Comment: I tried but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the correct order of services to start you need to add 2 things:

1. Set container's names to let them ping each other by these names (by means of docker bridge)
2. Enforce your app to wait for DB fully up before connect.

From point of this your Dockerfile could look like this (let we choose `wait-for-it`)

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE 8080
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN wget -q https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/raw/master/wait-for-it.sh -O /usr/bin/wait-for-it && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/wait-for-it
ADD /build/libs/assignment_4-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar spring-docker.jar
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/wait-for-it docker-mysql-container:3306 -t 120 ; java -jar spring-docker.jar
```

While `docker-compose.yml` should include

```
version: '3'

networks:
  database:

services:
  docker-mysql:
    networks:
      - database
    container_name: docker-mysql-container
    ...

  app:
    networks:
      - database
    container_name: app-container
    ...
```

And replace in your `application.properties` service's name `docker-mysql` with container's name `docker-mysql-container`